# GRPC calls do not work with mutliple python process

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, grpc

GRPC calls are not working when run in multiple processes. But can be done any number of times when run on main process / on one newly spawned process. All GRPC calls after creating second new process fails.

I setup a GRPC server using future.ThreadPoolExecutor: **start_server()** method

```
    some_server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    some_server_pb2_grpc.add_SomeInterfaceServicer_to_server(Server(), some_server)

    # bind the server to the port defined above
    some_server.add_insecure_port('[::]:{}'.format(self.server_port))

    # start the server
    some_server.start()
```

My python code:

```
# GRPC TEST - 1 : WORKS!! Single process calling GRPC client

from grpc_module.client import Client
from multiprocessing.process import Process
from utils import send_status_info


send_status_info() # Works

def my_loop():
    for i in range(10):
        send_status_info()

p = Process(target=my_loop)
p.start() # Works
p.join()
```

But GRPC calls start failing when done with multiple processes.

```
# GRPC TEST - 2 : FAILS!! Multiple process calling GRPC client

from grpc_module.client import Client
from multiprocessing.process import Process
from utils import send_status_info


send_status_info()

def my_loop():
    for i in range(10):
        send_status_info()

p = Process(target=my_loop)
p.start()
p.join()

p = Process(target=my_loop)
p.start()
p.join()
```

Is this related with unary GRPC setup.

If yes, how can i implement async GRPC here?

Please help.

**UPDATE:** My findings - GRPC calls reaches to GRPC Client code, but fails while contacting with server. On running this using python command line, when it gets stuck (as shown in method 2) i press ctrl+C, it terminates with a stack trace as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 145, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 154, in wait
    return self.poll(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 135, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
KeyboardInterrupt
```